# UICollectionView: Adding Tap Gesture Recognizer to collectionView super view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

The collection view is not called `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. When I add a Tap Gesture Recognizer to `collectionView` super view, It always response the tap gesture method.

Please help me, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInView(superView)
    return !CGRectContainsPoint(collectionView.frame, touchPoint)
}
```

and make sure the delegate is connected:

```
tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
```

Comment: When I set gesture  property cancelsTouchesInView to false ,  It's both to responsed that `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and `gesture method`.

Comment: Doing so that collection does not trigger `didSelectItemAtIndexPath ` .

Comment: So cool! It's work to me ! And I also   set gesture property cancelsTouchesInView to false!